# Specify the timestamp phrasing format when reading a .csv file with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .csv file with thousands of entries created by a data logger.

The format is more or less like this:

```
time                | data
01/07/2015 12:25:45 | 356.24
01/07/2015 12:25:50 | 357.24
01/07/2015 12:25:55 | 351.24
01/07/2015 12:26:00 | 357.20
01/07/2015 12:26:05 | 356.32
...
```

When I read the file using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename,  parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Some dates are recognised wrong for some reason, therefore I would like to specify the date format string manually, being the de format string `format_str = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'`

How can I do that?

Comment: You could do this a post-process step so don't pass args `parse_dates` and `infer_datetime_format` and then after loading do `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')` but the date parser is usually robust enough to handle this, can you post examples of where it's going wrong as it maybe invalid data in the first place

Comment: I'll try that and come back. I'll post an example of both results.

Answer (score 0):

[The `pandas.read_csv` function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) does not only take a `parse_dates=` argument, but also a `date_parser=` argument. With the `date_parser=` argument, you can specify your own function for parsing dates.

Like this:

```
def myparser(x):
    return datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

df = pd.read_csv(filename,  parse_dates=True, date_parser=myparser)
```

This should ensure that your dates are always parsed only with that format.

It is also better to parse the dates while reading the csv, not afterwards, since you won't have to load all the strings into memory first, then convert them, but rather convert them on the fly.

It is more memory efficient.

Comment: Totally agree, but I need to load it first since I'm making an app for monkeys, and monkeys don't know what they do, specially talking about formats of dates.